# python datetime instance check with date returns true

Tags: python, datetime, isinstance

I have a 2 objects, one is datetime and the other is date object. When I want to check the type of object using isinstance(python's preferred way), I get a little absurd results

```
>>> from datetime import date, datetime
>>> a=date.today()
>>> b=datetime.now()
>>> isinstance(a, date)
True
>>> isinstance(a, datetime)
False
>>> isinstance(b, date)
True       # this should be False
>>> isinstance(b, datetime)
True
```

Why datetime object instance check with date returning true? Currently I am using `type` to overcome this issue, but isn't a workaround?

```
>>> type(a) == date
True
>>> type(a) == datetime
False
>>> type(b) == date
False
>>> type(b) == datetime
True
```

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py#L1562

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why datetime object instance check with date returning true

there's no workaround, it works as intended, since `datetime` is a subclass of `date` and [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) returns `True` for subclasses, as the docs say. I think using `type()` is the only way for you here.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, date

>>> datetime.__mro__
(datetime.datetime, datetime.date, object)

>>> issubclass(datetime, date)
True
```

Comment: The documentation shows the similar information : https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html (search for "Subclass relationships).

Answer (score 2):

The `datetime` class is a subclass of `date`.

The Python library creates this inheritance relationship so that you can use a `datetime` where a `date` is wanted. The rationale for that is that a `datetime` object includes a date in it. If you ignore the time or use a fixed time (such as midnight) then it makes sense to use it as a `date` object.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types) mentions the class hierarchy:

> Subclass relationships:
>
> ```
> object
>     timedelta
>     tzinfo
>         timezone
>     time
>     date
>         datetime
> ```